# how to directly switch on another UITabBar?

Tags: cocoa-touch, tabbar, ibaction

by button press i want to go to the last tabbar item:
here is the code :

In my **AppDelegate** :

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController1, navController2, navController3, navController4];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

and In my **ViewController** here is the action :

```
- (IBAction)registrationFormBtnPressed:(id)sender {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;

    RegisterViewController *rigstr = [[RegisterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController" bundle:nil];

   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:rigstr animated:YES];
}
```

**RegisterViewController** is my *TabBarController*

I want to clik on the uibutton from first TabBar and it must go to the Last (4) tab bar

How to do it please pelase help me

i dont understand how to go directly to the last TabBar

Thank you in advance

Please Help me out

Thanks Gusy I've Solved My Problem, But one more thing i want to add

it go to the selected index but how to select the tabbar item when i go to the selected index ?

Comment: Thanks Gusy I've Solved My Problem, But one more thing i want to add in it, i go to the selected index but how to select the tabbar item when i go to the selected index ? means i'm on the first tab and by wrting one line i'm successed to go to the last tabbar item, but it doesn\t select 4th index it remains highlight the first tabbar item

Comment: The name of the class is `UITabBar`, not `UITABBAR`, and this question is also not about Xcode.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks i have edit it, but please can u help to solve this issue, i have gone to my desire UITabBar, but its showing the previous selection not the selected item, selected index is still highlighted

Comment: "how to select the tabbar item when i go to the selected index ?" - I don't understand this.

Comment: @H2CO3: 
By Adding this line to my IBAction:
" self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2; "

It goes to the third TAB, but still highligting my first TAB instead of 3rd one

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. What about the other tabs?